# MachineKey.Unprotect not working between DEV server and Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, encryption

In a web app I have an encryption and decryption method that use `MachineKey.Protect` and `MachineKey.Unprotect`.  It all works fine from a single machine, either DEV or my local machine.  But when I encrypt something on the server, I can't decrypt it on my local machine.

On the server, I went to the Web Site Machine Key page, and generated a unique validation and decryption key, and put that in my `web.config` under `system.web/machineKey`.  Also tried it with and without `compatibilityMode`.  On the server, `Generate a unique key for each application` is off.

What am I missing?

[image: Current machine key]

```
<machineKey 
  decryption="Auto" 
  validation="SHA1" 
  validationKey="9815F5A1AA9DB2F6A370548D58304A21F0792D63A08A1B34BD498059F65DA1484A783187CF798B40BED1E519BA40DBE9E135E952D319D2F8AA55D852CD77EE73"
  decryptionKey="DFD8FF5374C89B18746D58DE864224C4A941622431550A3E"
  compatibilityMode="Framework45"/>
```

(Yes, that's my validationKey and decryptionKey - it's dev and I'll change it once it works)